# Preciso criar uma expressão regular para validar um CamelCase

Tags: java, regex

Bom Dia a todos, espero que possam me ajudar. Preciso de uma regex ou até uma ideia de como inserir um espaço para expressões CamelCase.
Ou seja inserir um espaço para cada letra maiuscula da palavra.
Em java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex : `/[A-Z]/g`

Desta forma, pode encontrar todas as maiúsculas.

[Teste](https://regex101.com/r/rR7dI5/1)

Então no código pode usar algo como:

```
String s = "TudoMaiúsculoSemEspaçoQuemFezIsso";
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(s);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int extraFeed = 0;
while(m.find()){
    if(m.start()!=0){
        out = out.insert(m.start()+extraFeed, " ");
        extraFeed++;
    }
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Por que você usou o Matcher e o Pattern?

Comment: E Obrigado funcionou aqui para mim,
eu só queria uma explicação por ter usado as duas classes q eu citei
Matcher e Pattern

Comment: @Stan https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html